# Button redirects depending on the login status

Tags: php

i am new to PHPcodimg, i am developing an online food ordering system. I have to redirect  the buy button to a specific page only when am logged in. Here is my code.. but didnt get the desired output.

Restaurant.php

```
 <?php       
 session_start();
 ?>
----html code----
       <div class="col-md-7 buy">
         <?php
            if($_SESSION['logged'] == 1) {?>
                    <a class="morebtn hvr-rectangle-in" href="orders-list.php">buy</a>
                    <?php } else {?>
                    <a class="morebtn hvr-rectangle-in" href="login.php">buy</a>

                    <?php } ?>
```

Login.php

```
<?php

 define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
 define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
 define('DB_DATABASE', 'foodchain');
 $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

 session_start();
 error_reporting(0);

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // username and password sent from form 

  $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
  $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);


  $sql = "SELECT email,password FROM user_register WHERE email = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);


  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

  if($count == 1) {

      $_SESSION['logged']=1;
     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

     header('Location:http://localhost:8080/FOOD%20CHAIN/index.php');
  }else {

      $logmsg = "Invalid Username or Password";


  }
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your buttons are the same, only the href attributes are different so you can be thinking that your code doesn't work  whereas it's works !

```
<a class="morebtn hvr-rectangle-in" href="orders-list.php">buy</a>
<?php } else {?>
<a class="morebtn hvr-rectangle-in" href="login.php">buy</a>
```

Comment: I guess by "buttons are the same", you refer to fact that they both have text "buy" in them.

Comment: Thank you @Lucas Duval I got the solution. Refered to a youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oDlU4-7aDQ